# Play video in Custom App in sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I need to play videos from Assert library with description below.
Can any one give the solution.
I used Mediaplayer.JS from default 15 hive folder its not working.
This is my code

```
<script src="/sites/dev/_Layouts/15/SP.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/dev/MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.js">
</script>
<div id="MediaPlayerHost">
   <script>
        var MediaURL = URL;
        mediaPlayer.createMediaPlayer(
    document.getElementById('MediaPlayerHost'),
    'MediaPlayerHost',
    '500px', '333px',
    {
        displayMode: 'Fullscreen',
        mediaTitle: 'Sample',
        mediaSource: MediaURL,
        autoPlay: true,
        loop: false,
        mediaFileExtensions: 'wmv;wma;avi;mpg;mp3;3gp;mp4;',
        silverlightMediaExtensions: 'wmv;wma;mp3;'
    });
             </script>
<div id='MediaPlayerHost'>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your code look like, what have you done to debug? What is happening? We need information to help you identify your issue, not write the application for you.

Comment: I have added my code